# Looking for a nice expression of these functions in terms of trig functions

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing

I have come across three sinusoidal functions f1, f2, and f3 which, up to scaling and translation, are very close to each other.  When normalized and plotted together, they are hard to tell apart.  For example, if I subtract f2 from f1, the difference is between $0$ and $2\times10^{-2}$.  This is illustrated in the first graphic directly below.

[image: fig. 1]

I do not know the actual expression of these three functions, nor if such a form exists.  That is my question.  I am trying to figure out if these data points conform to a nice expression--that is, not just an ugly polynomial fitted with meaningless coefficients, but something meaningful in terms of trigonometric functions.

Or maybe the three functions are not particularly interesting in themselves, but are converging to some meaningful expression.

In case it is of help, when I take the discrete Fourier transform of f1 minus f2, I get the result plotted in the second graphic below.

[image: fig. 2]

Comment: Take a look at $\cos(kx^2)$ for various values of $k$. Those have similar looks to them.

Comment: @alex.jordan Yes, this is working.  Thanks.

Comment: @alex.jordan Although I can't get an exact fit using such a form.

Comment: @alex.jordan Oops, I spoke too soon.  The form you propose has some similarity, but is still far from a good fit.

Comment: You can mark the points where the curve passes through the mean value (0.5 or 0.01 on your plots) and fit a simple increasing function to them, probably a power function $at^b$. Then fit $A\cos(at^b)+B\sin(at^b)$ to the curve. In other words, one fit to find the time-changing transformation that makes the wave periodic, another to fit a periodic function to the curve (second step being Fourier expansion in general).

Comment: Take the DFT of the signal and see what frequencies comprise it.

Comment: Reminds me of the passband response of type I Chebyshev filters. So you might be able to use Chebyshev polynomials to fit these curves. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, it appears that you have a sinusoidal wave whose frequency increases as $x$ increases. If you take any even or odd function $f$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f$ concave up on $\mathbb{R}_+$, then $\cos\left(f(x)\right)$ will give you a graph like this. Using $f(x)=kx^2$ is one option, but using $f(x)=kx^{1+a}$ with $a>0$ will be similar. And there are many more options, like $f(x)=\sinh(kx)$ or $f(x)=\cosh(kx)-1$. See if you can find something that fits your curves.

You could also try to plot $f$ straight from your curves, by applying different branches of $\arccos$ at the turning points. Since your curve moves up and down from $0$ to $1$, you would first apply $y\mapsto2y-1$ to obtain values to apply branches of $\arccos$ to.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Yes, I like the idea of plotting $f$ straight from the curves.  I actually know what the critical points are.  The minima are at 110 (i.e. $11/36 \pi$) and 180 degrees, for example.  So I need a function which can satisfy $f(11/36 \pi)=f(\pi)$.

Comment: I think you want $f(0)=0$, $f(110)=\pi$, and then $f(\sim155)=3\pi/2$ and $f(180)=2\pi$, etc. So every time you reverse direction, take a new segment of $\cos$ to invert.